# Marker Image Drawable change GoogleMap V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have added markers in google map control using google map api v2 version but How to change Marker Background image when marker click event.

[image]

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
arg0.setIcon  //Not show in List setIcon method Google API V2 Version
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you used MarkerOptions mapMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Your title will be here");

mapMarker .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));?

Comment: yes this way i m set the marker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override map `onMarkerClick()` and change icon for the marker clicked.

```
private Marker changedMarker = null;

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if(changedMarker != null) {
        changedMarker.setIcon(defaultIcon);    // sets default icon
        changedMarker = null;
    }
    marker.setIcon(icon);    // icon is the Bitmap you want
    changedMarker = marker;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: setIcon not find google api v2 method. i am pressing Ctrl+space but showing list -setDraggble,setPosition,setSnippest,setTitle,setvisibles,showinfowindo not showing setIcon method in list.

Comment: I see it. Here is the description on the official android site http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setIcon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor)

Comment: I have add screenshot plz check

Comment: I don't know how to help you with that. I see the function, and it is also in official documentation.

Comment: Thanx @Boban S. I am not used updated play service lib that's reason icon method not show. After updating play service lib showing setIcon Method

Comment: how to set default image again when another marker click

Comment: you can set the default icon in `onMapClick` also

Comment: ya i know but when marker click and i m pressing another marker then old marker set default image (i.e 2 marker when 1st marker click then 1 set new image after 2 marker click then 1 set old image) how to check

Comment: i'm not sure that I understood you what you want to accomplish. with this solution you have reference to last clicked marker, so you can do with it whatever you want.